# parenthese matching in special cases

Tags: regex

I'm working on a parser, and in an expression such as

```
(-4 + 5)-2
( -4 + 5 ) - 2   
( -4 + 5 )-2
-4 + 5-2 
-4 + 5 - 2
```

I want to be able to

- match `-4` in this expression as a negative number `-4`
- match `-2` as the operator `-` and the number `2`

so in the above expressions, I want to be able to split the first three into [`(`, `-4`, `+`, `5`, `)`, `-`, `2`] and the last two into [`-4`, `+`, `5`, `-`, `2`]

I have tried using [noncapture groups](http://fiddle.re/q1xnv), however, they haven't done me much help. I do know that I'll have to recognize that if there is a closing parenthesis behind an expression such as `-2` to take it as an operator and a number.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex **as** my parser, I would use it to generate valid integers or variable names. Then I would tokenize and decide if there is no integer preceding a `-` then it is unary minus.  Just my opinion.

Comment: Regex is probably the wrong tool for this job, what are you trying to accomplish and in what language?

Comment: What if you treated binary and unary minuses as the same token: `(`, `-`, `4`, `+`, `5`, `)`, `-`, `2` ? You can figure it out at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

[Regexps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are good for working with [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Regular languages are context free. Your expressions aren't context free. (For example because it depends on the context if `-` is interpreted as an operator or a sign.) Thus they don't form a regular language, thus you can't parse them with regular expressions.